# Trigger Style on One Column of GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, textblock, multitrigger

My question is similar to [WPF Grid - How to apply a style for just one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851511/wpf-grid-how-to-apply-a-style-for-just-one-column) but applies to a `GridView` inside of a `ListView`

I'm trying to apply a trigger that will change the color of text within a `TextBlock` only in a given column within the `GridView`. If I take out the line commented `THIS` each textblock in the row is affected.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="MyGridView" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyleNew}">
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Option" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Option}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Dir" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Directory}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Status" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Overheating">
                                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" From="White" To="Red" Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

What changes to that line would make it so that only the 5<sup>th</sup> column which contains the text block is affected by the multitrigger?

**[EDIT 1]** Added code for `GridView`

**[EDIT 2]** I modified the last `GridViewColumn` to give it its own style

**[EDIT 3]** Removed the `DisplayMemberBinding` and added a `Setter` property... it works :).

Updated source code to reflect correct answer.

Comment: You're giving too little information. Paste your whole code about ListView. How are you using GridView in it and are you generating everything off viewmodels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be moving the style to the column's template:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                     <!-- Style here without additional condition -->
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but my code for the trigger isn't changing the text color...

Comment: @aqua: Any [binding error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)? What does your code look like?

Comment: Well the text 'Overheating' shows up in the appropriate column, but the animation either doesn't trigger or isn't working properly.

Comment: @aqua: You did not do what is necessary as i showed, you cannot use `DisplayMemberPath` and a `CellTemplate` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use multi-binding and pass GridViewColumn & GridView into the converter, which decides COLUMN number. You can pass those using RelativeSource binding which will work automatically. There is no "Column" property as far I can tell.

In conveter you do GridView.Columns.IndexOf(YourColumn). Alternatively you just change your viewmodel and add new property, "StyleColumn", and use bindable columns [WPF MVVM: how to bind GridViewColumn to ViewModel-Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection)

Comment: I don't know what this means, and I'm not using MVVM.