# Shared styling in WPF

Tags: wpf, styling

What if I wanted to make all `TextBlock` elements in UserControl, or section of a UserControl, have `FontWeight="Bold"` and `TextAlignment="Right"`? Is there some style I can set for `TextBlock` elements within a certain scope so I don't have to repeat all those attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this in your resources, all your textblocks become the same.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>
```

Alternatively, you can also subclass from `TextBlock` (say, `BoldTextBlock`) and use it as the target type. This is so you can use regular textblocks in the same control as special textblocks

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type BoldTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: For bonus points, how could I do that for something like `Grid.Column`. It doesn't seem to work the way you showed me above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean for `Grid.Column`. Do you mean use a specific style for say... just one column? Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/853082/1732567

Comment: I want all my `TextBlock` elements in grid column 0. They are labels - their input elements are all in grid column 1. I'd like to avoid repeating all that markup as well.

Comment: @ProfK You can use a `<Trigger>` in `Style.Trigger` for that. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851511/302677) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a style with no `x:Key` and it will be applied to all items of the specified `TargetType` within that scope

For example, to make all TextBlock have `FontWeight="Bold"` and `TextAlignment="Right"` within a specific `UserControl` only, you can use something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. Hard decision, but your answers were the same and @Vlad beat you by a few seconds.